# An exception occurred while reading data from Linq query result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I got the below below error on page load. When it hits the List() method on page load.

Please note that I already got values on variable query in below code.

But in else part after executing line:

```
JtableReturnTypeObj.Records = query.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
```

hitting the catch block and showing below error.

> Value cannot be null.
>   Paramater name: expression

Error got hit in below code else part after executing its first line.

```
public JtableListReturnType List(string Params, int jtStartIndex = 0, 
                                 int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null, 
                                 string jsonAdvancedSearchFilterCriteria = null, int? id = 0)
{
    var query = (   //Provided Linq code here // )

    if (jsonAdvancedSearchFilterCriteria != null)
    {
        var searchResult = QueryBuilder.AdvancedSearchQueryBuilder(query, 
 jsonAdvancedSearchFilterCriteria, false);
        //onloadtext party
        JtableReturnTypeObj.Records = searchResult.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
        JtableReturnTypeObj.Result = "OK";
        JtableReturnTypeObj.TotalRecordCount = searchResult.Count();
    }
    else
    {
        JtableReturnTypeObj.Records = query.Skip(jtStartIndex).Take(jtPageSize).ToList();
        JtableReturnTypeObj.Result = "OK";
        JtableReturnTypeObj.TotalRecordCount = query.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expect you pass null as a parameter somewhere in your AdvancedSearchQueryBuilder method. Since jsonAdvancedSearchFilterCriteria is default null, this may lead to some errors.